# How to convert multiple table to column of tables in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes in pandas.

Now I want to merge them to a single dataframe in which each extra column corresponds to a list of elements corresponding to the key in the dataframe2. one table is like a child of other(the second table has a foriegn key which references to the the primary key of the table1).
For example,

[image]

I don't know any inbuilt methods to do such operation.So It would be great if you help me in merging the columns.

 Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hello, could you update your post to expose what you have tried so far?

Comment: Some problem with answer?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `list`, add missing values by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) and add to `df1` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df22 = (df2.groupby('City_name')
           .agg(list)
           .reindex(df1['City_name'].unique(), fill_value=[]))

df = df1.join(df22, on='City_name')
```

Comment: reindex allows `[]` but `.fillna` doesn't weird. Got to know reindex accepts `[]`

Comment: Thanks for the method. 
This might be possible if I have only one column in the df2 other than key, but if I have like around many(say 100) columns in df2 which are to be merged in the same fashion. How should I do it?(Its very hard to manually do for each and every column and if we use a for loop then complexity might increase)

Comment: @nachiappanvenkatesh - then remove `['Humidity']` only. Answer was editd.

Comment: @Ch3steR - yes, agree.

Answer (score 1):

First, group city and make `Humidity` to a list using [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html), then use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on `City_name`. Now, fill missing values with `[]` using [`pd.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)

```
g = df2.groupby('City_name').agg(list)
out = df1.merge(g, left_on='City_name', right_index=True, how='outer')
out['Humidity'] = out['Humidity'].fillna({i:[] for i in out.index})

  City_name  Temp   Humidity
0     city1    47  [1, 2, 7]
1     city2    34         []
2     city3    83        [9]
```